# How create TRectangle with rounded corners in Firemonkey?

Tags: android, firemonkey, rounded-corners

I'm building an app for Android using RAD Studio 10.1 and I need to create an TRectangle with rounded corners.

There is an easy/native way to create an TRectangle with rounded corners?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сhange the `XRadius` and `YRadius` of your Rectangle.